# Function being read as a variable and and working in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I want to have a function recur in python, but when I call the function in itself, it instead reads it as a variable, breaking the game. Here is the important code.

```
def City(WCity):
    if WCity == "v":
        print sty.BOLD + "WELCOME DO VIRIDIAN CITY" + sty.END
        print "What would you like to do?"
        print "Press 0 to look around"
        print "Press 1 to Go to the pokemon center"
        print "Press 2 to Go to the PokeMart"
        print "Press 3 to go back"
        print "Press 4 to go foward"
        PlayerChoice = int(input())
        if PlayerChoice == 0:
            CP.Viridian()
            City(WCity)
        if PlayerChoice == 1:
            print "Welcome to the Pokemon Center, please wait while we heal your pokemon to full health"
            for i in xrange(0,len(Player.Pokemon)):
                Player.Pokemon[i].HP = Player.Pokemon[i].MaxHP
            time.sleep(2)
            print "Your Pokemon's health was restored"
            time.sleep(.5)
            City(WCity)
```

Comment: What are WCity and CP? What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I think you'd be better of with an endless loop here to avoid the recursion. `While True:` will repeat the function until you break it. P.S.: function names and variables should be lower case.

Comment: Where does CP come from? Why is WCity never set? What exact ist the Output?